# Unity car AI with navigation mesh

Tags: unity, ai

I made a car AI that works by raycasting for obstacle avoidance to steering and accelerate. I want to know how can I implement a navigation mesh for better obstacle avoidance.

How do I implement a navigation mesh, and use my car as the navigation agent?

Comment: Of course it is possible; [the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) provides more than enough information to do exactly what your asking (I know because I followed it several years ago). - 1 for lack of sufficient research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are [NavMesh Obstacles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html). These obstacles aren't baked into the Navmesh, but instead sit on top of it providing dynamic obstacles that should be avoided.

A good tutorial and introduction can be found [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/navmesh-obstacles?playlist=17105)